# Опрос проводят или делают?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли сказать "сделать опрос" или лучше все-таки его "провести"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, большой разницы в этих словосочетаниях нет, но лучше отдать предпочтение слову "провести", так как опрос - это процесс, а процесс проводится, а не делается